# How to remove search bars on Google Maps in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have the latitude and longitude of a location.Need to display it into webview.Using this url :http://www.google.com/maps?q=latitude,longitude .
But this will display the search bar with coordinate. Does anyone know how to hide search bar and other things from webview ?

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" & latitude & "," & longitude & "&output=classic")
```

Source:
[Google map help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/WhJxTxLktco)

**Update:**

> Unfortunately Classic Maps is no longer available.

You can read the announcement [**here**](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/Zgqoqsvfipc/oJlbSvPdYCQJ)

Classic Maps been replaced by *Lite Mode*

Comment: Classic Maps been replaced by Lite Mode!!

Comment: I could able to load html content to the webview.It worked for me